# Public key - Application error

Tags: heroku, ssh, key, public

Hey I'm new in programming `Facebook` applications and I wanted to start with `Heroku` but I have big problems to start working with it.

After I logged on in the console I am asked whether I want to create a `SSH public key`. When I'm entering yes I get the message that it's generating a public key to `C:/Users/Test/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

Then it says

```
Uploading SSH public key C:/Users/Test/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.. - failed.
! Application error.
```

Can anybody help me? :(

Comment: What version of the Heroku Toolbelt are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Here I have the same problem...

The solution I found was:

1) Open your file "C:/Users/Test/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" with any ext editor.

2) Copy the content, begininig with "ssh-rsa" until "==".

3) go to https://dashboard.heroku.com/account

4) copy this to "add new ssh key", press Add key.

Comment: this didn't work for me "Could not add SSH key. The key was invalid."

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error you may have not run the **ssh-keygen.exe** present in **..\Git\bin** then you must enter the address of your ssh key in your case it seems to be **C:/Users/Test/.ssh/id_rsa** after that you should login .