# in heroku login ssh public key cannot be generated for facebook apps

Tags: facebook, heroku

I downloaded the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/), then i ran the cmd and ran the command `Heroku login`.

I entered my credentials after that as per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook#heroku-account-and-tools-setup

I got the message:

`Could not find an existing public key.
Would you like to generate one? [Yn]`

I typed `y` then I got the following message

```
Generating new SSH public key.

!    Could not generate key: 'ssh-keygen' is not recognized as an internal or e
xternal command,
 !    operable program or batch file.
```

Then I did some more research and ran the `ssh-keygen.exe` present in `..\Git\bin`

However I got the same error as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435939/public-key-application-error).

Comment: I got my mistake I had not created any file in **..\Git\bin** when running the **ssh-keygen.exe** then we must type the full location in my case it was **..\Git\bin\myfile**

Answer (score 3):

you should try running the git command prompt. Which you can find under \programfiles\git\Git Bash. In case you do not have git then install from http://git-scm.com/download/win.

Answer (score 0):

add the GIT **C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin** to the PATH environment variable before the heroku path and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Upon trying Heroku tonight I got the same final error: 
under windows, it is just a matter of %path% (bad heroku install package).

solution: simply execute 'heroku login' within the ssh.keygen.exe directory:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin

Then everything works fine with no more changes.

Comment: the unrelated link at the end is called ... **spam**

Comment: @Massimiliano: Please do not include signatures, links to your personal site, or other personal things at the end of your posts.